# UIImageView outlet of Custom TableViewCell nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I created a `UITableViewCell` prototype cell on storyboard, then I link it to my `ImageViewCell`which inherit from `UITableViewCell`. I created `IBOutlet` for each control on prototype cell, it contains some `UILabel` and a `UIImageView`. When I tried to populate data into those control, `UILabel` work well but `UIImageView` always nil and won't display any image. Code:

```
@interface ImageTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) Post *post;

// set value for post
- (void)setPost:(Post *)post;
@end

@implementation ImageTableViewCell
{
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *pointLabel;
    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

}
- (void)setPost:(Post *)post
{
    _post = post;

    // update ui
    titleLabel.text = self.post.title;
    descriptionLabel.text = self.post.descriptions;
    pointLabel.text = self.post.point;    

    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mylocalimage.png"]];

}
@end
```

In my controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(feedData == nil || [feedData count] == 0)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    NSDictionary *postData = [feedData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // prepare data to pass to table view cell
    Post *post = [[Post alloc] init];    
    post.title = [postData objectForKey:@"title"];
    post.descriptions = [postData objectForKey:@"description"];
    post.total_likes = [postData objectForKey:@"total_likes"];
    post.total_shares = [postData objectForKey:@"total_shares"];
    post.image = [postData objectForKey:@"image"];

    ImageTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ImageCell"];;
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[ImageTableViewCell alloc] init];
    }

    [cell setPost:post];


    return cell;
}
```

All the `UILabel` work well, but `UIImageView`'s image never been set, I tried to set it with a local image but still not work, after of some investigation, I found out that at the time I set image for `imageView`, it always nil. So how can I overcome this?

**Update**

Linking image[image]

Comment: Whats `sd_setImageWithURL` it looks like you are trying to download an image, with a nil placeholder? Have you checked that this function is working as you expect

Comment: As I mentioned above, I tried to set it with a local image, but it still not working

Comment: Did you forget to link the IBOutlet in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes, I drag and drop it from storyboard, and I didn't think I made anything wrong with the linking, because `UILabel` work fine, only `UIImageView` always nil

Comment: the bullet point next to the variable is black, right?

Comment: I updated the linking image

Comment: try changing the variable name to something else than imageView

Comment: I changed it to thumbnailImage and still got the same

Comment: @pe60t0 actually that work. Could you please post an answer with brief explain why variable name matter here so I can accept your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing the variable name of your `UIImageView` to something else than "imageView". The reason for this is that `UITableViewCell` itself has a property named "imageView". So when you are setting the property it must try to set the superclass' property which is not linked to your outlet hence the result.